# Outlook web app notifications not working

Tags: outlook.com, outlook, outlook-on-the-web

the agency where I am working at is switching to Office 365 to handle emails and other stuff.

I can't get desktop notification to work on Outlook, the browser based version.

I'm running on Win10 Pro, I activated the notification inside OWA settings, Office 365 settings and gave consent to Chrome to deliver notifications from the site.
Despite all this when I receive a new email (with the OWA open in a tab) there is no notification whatsoever.

I don't even know if this could be related but I am also using Microsoft Teams and the notifications from that are working just fine.

What am I missing?